# Pagelayout question related to account

Tags: admin

hi i have a page layout related to account.In that one section named account detail which is a standard section.on the detail page it is displaying with the other name.now i need to rename the account detail section ,how can i do that ? any idea?

Comment: your question is very unclear. elaborate more on this. is that Account detail section named differently in view screen and edit screen? And you want to change that on edit screen only? Is that what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

If it a standard section you can't rename it. Standard page sections are read only.

Else you can create a new section with your required name and move all the field from standard section.

You can place the fields in same order like standard one.